# helper with block and raw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

Given an helper like this one

```
def helper_method(name, &block)
  result = block_given? ? capture(&block)
  ...
  result
end
```

And this HAML view

```
= raw helper_method do
  .content
    some html content
```

result is nil when used with raw. why?

I know how to solve this, there is many way to avoid the situation but what I want to know is why I'm loosing the block?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using  `()` the block is not reaching the `helper_method`.

Basically the `raw`method is the one getting the block.

try : `raw helper_method {}`

It's one of the main differences between the `do end` and the `{}` blocks.

Or use the `()` to prevent the ambiguity.

Comment: Actually, no, I am using to pass some options (). I didn't specify to make it short, but I'll investigate in that way. Thanks for you input

Comment: I mean something like this: `raw( helper_method do ... end )`. You are having problems with the precedence.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in the context of Haml, I don't see how I can do this

Comment: @unixcharles In order to make it work and sort of clean I can only think about creating a `Proc` and send it as the `helper_method` param with `&` or create a `raw_helper_method` just to get the block and add the `raw` to the `helper_method` return value. HAML won't give you a clear solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because i never user haml
but don't you need a end tag??

like this:

```
<%= raw helper_method do %> 

<% end %>
```

?

Comment: No, you don't need end tag in HAML

Comment: No, its one of the point of Haml, indentation close the block, like in python.